# Criar CONSTRAINT FOREINGN KEY com chave primaria tipo VARCHAR de outra tabela MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas uma chamada `_hardware_` e outra chamada `_responsavel_`. Na `_responsavel_` tenho uma `Primary Key` chamada `NIP` do tipo `VARCHAR(8)`. Criei um campo chamado `NIP_RESP` também `VARCHAR(8)`, gostaria de referenciar a coluna `NIP` da tabela `_responsavel_` como `Foreign Key` na coluna `NIP_RESP` da tabela `_hardware`.

**Código**

```
ALTER TABLE hardware
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_NIP_RESP` FOREIGN KEY ( NIP_RESP ) REFERENCES responsavel ( NIP );
```

**Erro**

> failed : Cannot add   foreign key constraint

Cabe ressaltar que ambas são `NOT NULL DEFAULT VALUE 99999999`

Comment: algum dos campos está diferente em algum aspecto, a melhor forma de ver é dar um SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; e ver o ultimo erro relacionado a foreign key depois da sua tentativa

Comment: Ehp possível lhe reator